# Will running Wine & Virtual-Box at the same time cause problems?

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, wine

I heard that you can't install more than one virtualization software at the same time, such as wine and virtual box, because that will create many problems.

Now Wine is *not* a virtualization software, can I install it in Fedora 29 even though VBox is installed and running, without expecting any problems? Also, can I have winetricks installed as well as the other two?

Comment: Where did you hear that?

Comment: Not exactly sure...a tutorial website or Linux course probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install what ever you like, but running more than one virtualisation software may be bad (depending on how it dose virtualisation). They can interfere with each other, as they are trying to control special hardware.

However **Wine is not virtualisation software**, so it will be OK.

## Can you run more than one vm-system at the same time? (references

- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=59128
- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5559

Comment: Of interference? No, sorry. But if I come across it again, I'll comment it here for you.

Comment: I think that @stephenkitt was asking me, as the comment was on my answer. I added some references. Note Stephen asked you as similarly worded, but different, question, above.

Comment: Right, I was asking ctrl-alt-delor; thanks for the references! Upvoted. (It might be worth making it explicit that non-VMX virtualisers can run in parallel, *e.g.* QEMU in non-KVM mode.)

Comment: @StephenKitt I added a caviete. If you know more, then you can edit.